# Codeception unit test error: Class not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception, laragon

I followed Codeception's quick start guide (http://codeception.com/quickstart) and read their documentation (http://codeception.com/docs/05-UnitTests).

I have managed to set up the testing environment, and

1. Created the unit test file (`php codecept.phar generate:test unit ExampleTest`)
2. Run the test command (`php codecept.phar run unit ExampleTest`), which returns an error:

There was 1 error:

```
1) ExampleTest: Validation
 Test  tests\unit\ExampleTest.php:testValidation
                                  
  [Error] Class 'User' not found  
                                  
#1  ExampleTest->testValidation
#2  C:\laragon\www\kario\vendor\bin\codecept.phar:5
```

How does the test file know which PHP file to run the test on?

My laragon project is named *kario*, and sits in `C:\laragon\www\kario\resources\views\pages\orders` while the test unit file is in `C:\laragon\www\kario\vendor\bin\tests\unit`.

Comment: Have you got autoloading working in your application code? autoloading is your best option, but if you don't use it, then you will have to require_once each file separately.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question too and found the answer for myself.  Posted here http://phptest.club/t/beginner-codeception-unit-test-help/1849  but also, here you go:

First, some details. I am using Codeception v2.4.1, powered by PHPUnit 7.1.4. The answer is:

In `codeception.yml`, add these two lines:

```
    settings:
        bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
```

Here `_bootstrap.php` can be whatever you want the name of your bootstrap file to be.

You must place `_bootstrap.php` in each of the following directories as follows:

```
tests/unit/_bootstrap.php
tests/functional/_bootstrap.pp
tests/acceptance/_bootstrap.php
```

In my `tests/unit/_bootstrap.php` file, I placed the following code:

```php
<?php
use Codeception\Util\Autoload;
Autoload::addNamespace('myclassnamespace', __DIR__ . '/../../Classes/');
```

To make sure I had the right path to Classes, I used `trigger_error(__DIR__)` in my `_bootstrap.php` before I added the `Autoload` line.

Then in my `tests/unit/TestAddCest.php`, I placed the following line at the beginning of the file:

```php
<?php
use mynamespace;
```

And in my test function looks like this (note the instantiation of the User class):

```php
    public function tryToTest(UnitTester $I)
    {
      $user = new mynamespace\User('someusername');
      $I->assertEquals('someusername', $user->username);
    }
```

I hand typed that function because I'm not on the same machine with the code and didn't feel like getting it over, so it may have a typo or bug, but you get the idea.

**Edit 05/01/2018:** someone else answered me on http://phptest.club:

It would be better to configure autoloading of your classes in `composer.json` and let Composer to do the rest, unless you try to avoid using Composer.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: I think your path for Autoload::addNamespace() would be __DIR__ . ‘\..\..\resources\views\pages\orders’